# set linux image size buildroot

Tags: linux, buildroot

My linux image generated thanks to buildroot is 4G. I want to deploy in my 16 GB mSata. Hence, I would like to extend the rootfs size.

With Yocto there are variable like IMAGE_ROOTFS_EXTRA_SPACE or IMAGE_ROOTFS_SIZE to do so. Is there any equivalence in buildroot ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Buildroot you should use `make menuconfig` command for configuration.

Here is an exemplary setup ext4 filesystem for buildroot version 2023.02-rc2:

```
Filesystem images ->
    [*] ext2/3/4 root filesystem
          ext2/3/4 variant (ext4) --->
    (rootfs) filesystem label
    (16G) exact size
```

This configuration sets variable `BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE` in `.config` file, but it should be noted that Buildroot authors discourage direct modification of it.

Unfortunately this option is not yet documented in user manual, but
for other options refer to:
https://buildroot.org/downloads/manual/manual.html

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution:

1. make menuconfig 2982:BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="24G"- 24G for experiment
2. Plug 32GB sdcard into host.
3. Run gparted and select /dev/sdc- sdc might vary depending on the host SD plut.
4. Delete all the existing partitions
5. sudo dd if=output/images/sdcard.img of=/dev/sdc bs=4M status=progress
6. sudo minicom -s - /dev/ttyUSB0; 115200 8n1 no flow control
7. Plug the flashed sdcard into rpi3mb
8. Log in
9. ## df / -h

Filesystem                Size      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/root                23.5G     47.6M     22.2G   0% /

Comment please.....